# MSBuild: How to recursively copy up to certain parent folders of an item

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following project structure

```
SolutionDir
  -src
    -Feature
    |---Feature.A
    |-----code
    |-------ViewA
    |---------FileA.cshtml
    |---Feature.B
    |-----code
    |-------ViewB
    |---------FileB.cshtml
```

I want this to be copied over to dest directory in the following structure

```
-OutputDir
|--code
|----ViewA
|------ViewA.cshtml
|----ViewB
|------ViewB.cshtml
```

I'm using the following scripts in .csproj

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<ItemGroup>
  <FeatureViewFiles 
    Include="$(SolutionDir)src\Feature\Feature.*\code\**\*.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy 
  SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
  SourceFiles="@(FeatureViewFiles)" 
  DestinationFolder="OutputDir\code\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</Target>
```

Now because in my `Include` the wildcard starts from `Feature.*`, the `RecursiveDir` directive outputs `Feature.A\code\ViewA\`, while what I really want is for it to copy the folder structure starting from under `code` folder. Any idea how I would achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry but I'm afraid the answer is negative.

As I know it's expected behavior for Copy task. If you use wildcard in Feature.*, it won't pick the structure from ViewX. Only if you specify the Feature.A or Feature.B, the copy task can work as you expected. But i assume that's not you want, so I think the copy task can't satisfy your needs for this issue.

Apart from Copy task, there's a Exec task in which you can specify commands. It works like using command-line cmd.exe. So if there's any command or batch file can do this job, you can use the [Exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019) to call them. But for Copy task, for now it doesn't support the behavior to specify level of parent folders:(

**In addition:** I tried copy, xcopy but no luck. Maybe you can try [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) or any other tool. If they can work in command-line, then you can use exec command to involve them in your build target.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this is not possible.

Try searching Exec command, where you can specify multiple commands or can also use batch file which might be helpful in your case.